# Porting VxWorks intConnect API to linux

Tags: linux, interrupt, porting, vxworks

I am trying port VxWorks APIs to linux. It was working fine till I found intArchLib apis. How do I port int APIs (intConnect,intLock ...) to Linux.

intConnect : This api register an interrupt routine(ISR) for an interrupt vector(IRQ). This ISR will be invoked when registered interrupt occurs.

1. Is it possible to port without a kernel mode driver in Linux?
2. Is it possible to port without a user mode driver in Linux?

Please help me.

SS

Comment: You would probably get more responses if you described what that particular function does for the benefit of those without VxWorks experience.

Comment: The interrupt model between vxWorks and Linux are entirely different. Unless you actually understand BOTH, it will be difficult to do a port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reasonable way to port intConnect to Linux.  Said another way, intConnect is an API in vxWorks that ought not be used by device drivers directly.  One should use intConnect to implement other high abstraction interfaces.  For example, as of vxWorks 6.6, vxbIntConnect is implemented with intConnect.